# Defining a project "on", "in", or "about" something

Tags: prepositions

> To raise capital, our company defined a project on/in/about solar panels.

For defining the scope of a project, which preposition is correct?

Comment: IMO To raise capital, our company defined a project **about** solar panels is correct since the sentence is indicating a topic.

Answer (score 1):

Project on (topic where the project is about)

example:
Project on networking

or

Project about (something will talk about)

example:
project about solar winds

project about tower